# Read starts before the insert completes

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Transactional
    public void save(String myIds) 
    {
            synchronized (this) 
            {
                List<mydata> data = getDataToSaveOrUpdate(myIds);//Returns the new dataList and updates old data
                repository.saveAll(data);
                logger.info("request processed");
            }
        logger.debug("exiting the method");
    }
```

In this method if i sent the two same request with the difference between 0.5 sec what happens getDataToSaveOrUpdate method start reading data from repository before the previous request saveAll finishes the job.

**Note One thing i noticed that it will work properly once i removed @Transactional**

Answer (score -1):

Maybe what you need is [`LockModeType`(`PESSIMISTIC_WRITE`)](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/LockModeType.html).

Comment: No it does not work but it starts working idealy if i remove the @Transictional annotation

Answer (score -1):

Second request processing starts as soon as first thread exits synchronized block. Transaction might still not be committed by then. Transaction will only be committed after method execution is completed.

One possible solution is to add `synchronized` keyword to the method itself.

```
@Transactional
public synchronized void save(String myIds) {    
    List<mydata> data = getDataToSaveOrUpdate(myIds);//Returns the new dataList and updates old data
    repository.saveAll(data);
    logger.info("request processed");
    logger.debug("exiting the method");
}
```

One need to be very careful when using `synchronized` keyword. I don't know your exact need, may be it is a valid usage for your scenario.